Using book class, how to automatically include reference to preface in TOC
\documentclass[english,11pt,twosided,openright]{book}

\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind} %
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{roman}
\setcounter{page}{0}

\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection

\tableofcontents

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Preface (from addtocontents - wrong page number)}


\listoffigures

\listoftables

\chapter*{Preface - using default unnumbered chapter format} %

\noindent \hspace{80pt}OR

\section*{Preface - using default unnumbered section format} %

\clearpage

\pagenumbering{arabic} %
\setcounter{page}{0} %

\chapter{Chapter ONE}

\section{Section ONE}

Problem: no automatic inclusion of preface in TOC

\end{document}


Use \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Preface (from addtocontents - wrong page number)}  at the start of the chapter/section which you want to add to the toc

Your answer explicitly answers my question as posed and is valuable to us amateurs in its own right.  However, I have one query: should \frontmatter follow \begin{document} ?

You should add \addcontentsline after Preface (section/chapter).
Try this:
\documentclass[english,11pt,twosided,openright]{book}    
    
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind} %     
\usepackage{hyperref}    
    
\begin{document}    
    
\frontmatter    
    
\tableofcontents    
    
%\listoffigures    
%\listoftables    
    
\chapter*{Preface} %    
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Preface}                                                                         
    
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy                                        
eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam                                        
voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet                                         
clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit                                         
amet.  

\mainmatter

\chapter{Chapter ONE}

\section{Section ONE}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy
eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam
voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet
clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit
amet.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy
eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam
voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet
clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit
amet.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy
eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam
voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet
clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit
amet.

\end{document}

